# unquoted string in shell_exec

Tags: php, mysql, shell

I am try to run a query with like operator for shell command but every time it gives error of unquoted string

```
 $abc = shell_exec("mysql  --user=**** --password=**** --host=**** db -e
 
'SELECT TABLE_NAME,
       COLUMN_NAME 
 FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
 WHERE   COLUMN_NAME LIKE '\"'%lead%'\" 
 AND TABLE_NAME  LIKE '\"'%leads%'\"  "); '
```

it runs for single conditions seperaetly
like

```
WHERE   COLUMN_NAME LIKE '\"'%lead%'\"
```

or

```
WHERE TABLE_NAME  LIKE '\"'%leads%'\"
```

but with AND operator combined it gives unquoted string err . i tried by removeing and adding quotes , but not working
please suggest

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Why not use PHP's MySQL connector?

Comment: why don't you use `mysqli_*` functions in PHP instead? You cannot handle errors if you use `shell_exec()`

Answer (score 0):

if you want quotes to be part of the string, you need to escape it with backslash `\"`

Answer (score 0):

Just escape your quotes with backslash.

```
$abc = shell_exec("mysql --user=**** --password=**** --host=**** db -e 'SELECT TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '\"'%lead%'\" AND TABLE_NAME LIKE '\"'%leads%'\"'");
```

Comment: error : -  [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
shell_exec("mysql --user=**** --password=**** --host=**** db -e 'SELECT TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '\"'%lead%'\" AND TABLE_NAME LIKE '\"'%leads%'\"'");
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Isn't this the same answer than the one given by Peter Pivarc twelve minutes before yours?

Comment: err-  [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.